# Array problems with storing

Tags: c, pic

Have following code.

```
unsigned char raindays[31];
void midnat(void)   //thing to do at midnight. shift of date.
{
    int d;
    week_day++;
    if (week_day==7) week_day=0;
        r_regn=r_regn+today_rain;


    for (d==29;d>0;d--)
    {
        raindays[d]=raindays[d-1];
    }

    raindays[0]=0;


//  d--;


    raindays[30]=today_rain;
    today_rain=0;

}
```

But the "data" is not shiftet correct.
I want the data from "raindays[29]" to take the value from raindays[28]
and down to 0.
But it will not shift correct, only first "data" is correct, nothing else is moved.

Comment: Your problem statement is quite vague.  Can you tell us what's in `raindays` to start with, and what you expect to be in it afterwards?

Comment: Where does the week_day come from ? It's not global eh ? :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

1. You should use `=` in your `for` loop setup, not `==`.
2. Shouldn't the loop start at `30`, not `29`?
3. I think you're using the assignment operator backwards.  If you want to copy `raindays[29]` down to `raindays[28]`, and then propagate that value through to `raindays[27]`, etc. you need to use:

   ```
   raindays[d - 1] = raindays[d];
   ```

   Not the other way around.
4. You're not putting anything *in* `raindays[29]` before you start that copying loop.  That means you'll just be copying random data, even if you do make the above two fixes.

Alternate answers:

1. You still should use `=`, not `==`.
2. The loop still starts at the wrong place.
3. If you're trying to copy *up*, your assignment statement is correct, however:
4. You still need to put something *in* the array before you start copying.  Since you haven't shown the definition of `raindays`, it's hard to say if that's important or not.

Answer (score 3):

replace this

```
for (d==29;d>0;d--)
```

with

```
for (d=29;d>0;d--)
```

Comment: HAve also tried without "for". and just added many lines , like raindays[29]=raindays[28],  raindays[28]=raindays[27] . ect.

Comment: ` void midnat(void) //thing to do at midnight. shift of date.
 {int d;
 week_day++;
if (week_day==7) week_day=0;
r_regn=r_regn+today_rain;
 
raindays[29]=raindays[28];
raindays[28]=raindays[27];
raindays[27]=raindays[26];
raindays[26]=raindays[25];
raindays[25]=raindays[24];
ect........

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void midnat(void)  //thing to do at midnight. shift of date.
     {int d;
     week_day++;
    if (week_day==7) week_day=0;
    r_regn=r_regn+today_rain;


    for (d=30;d>0;d--)
{
    raindays[d-1]=raindays[d];

 }
   raindays[0]=0;


    //  d--;


     raindays[30]=today_rain;
    today_rain=0;

     }
```